# calling a ruby method in the ruby terminal

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal

i have a method that gives an amount of square numbers depending on the number a user gives. eg if the users input is 5, the result will be 1, 4, 9, 16, 25.
The method works. i was just wondering how to run this in the terminal. I know i need to do ruby squares.rb, which is the file name, but that just doesn't do anything afterwards. What i would like to happen is that someone could type squares(3), in the terminal, and get the result below it. im sure this is very simple aha, thanks.

```html
def squares(input)
  numbers = (1..input)
  numbers.each do |number|
    puts number * number
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding simplification to method - `def squre(n); 1.upto(n) { |x| puts x*x }; end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gets` method to get user input then parse it as int and call `squares` on it.

Try this

```
def squares(input)
  numbers = (1..input)
  numbers.each do |number|
    puts number * number
  end
end

def setup_input_loop
  loop do
    puts "Print square from 1 to n. Please enter n."
    input = gets.chomp.to_i
    squares(input)
    puts
  end
end

setup_input_loop
```

Comment: @b.herring Wait you want the someone to run it? One second I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah, i want someone else to use it in the terminal. i've made it work with gets.chomp. but i was just wondering if you could do it literally by just typing squares(3) in the terminal.

Comment: @b.herring I have updated my answer. What you are asking for is achievable is using `eval` but not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *shell* function that calls that ruby method:

```
squares() {
    ruby -e '
      def squares(input)
        numbers = (1..input)
        numbers.each do |number|
          puts number * number
        end
      end
      squares ARGV.shift.to_i
    ' -- "$1"
}
```

then

```
$ squares 3
1
4
9
```

---

If, by "ruby terminal", you mean `irb` then add that method to your `~/.irbrc` file, then you can do

```
$ cat ~/.irbrc
def squares(input)
  numbers = (1..input)
  numbers.each do |number|
    puts number * number
  end
end

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> squares(3)
1
4
9
=> 1..3
irb(main):002:0>
```

---

Just for fun, monkey patching the Integer class:

```
$ cat ~/.irbrc
class Integer
  def squares
    1.upto(self) {|n| puts n * n}
    self
  end
end
```

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 3.squares
1
4
9
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation that can be executed without prepending `ruby` to the filename and also doesn't make an infinite loop.

```
# make a file called square_loop.rb

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def squares(input)
  numbers = (1..input)
  numbers.each do |number|
    puts number * number
  end
end

def setup_input_loop
  loop do
    puts "Print square from 1 to n. Please enter n or X to exit"
    input = gets.chomp
    exit if input.downcase == 'x' 
    squares(input.to_i)
    puts
  end
end

setup_input_loop
```

Then just make it executable with

```
chmod +x square_loop.rb
```

Then call it from your terminal with 
    ./square_loop.rb

Though prepending ruby works too

```
ruby square_loop.rb
```